# Player won't display that it is added

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to add a new player but it won't display and i keep getting a rollback. I've tried using hidden_field for my user_id but it didn't seem to do anything. Are there any other alternatives of doing this? I'm pretty sure its something so small that I have to change.  Please help.

Player controller:

```
def new
        @players = Player.new
    end

def create
        @players = Player.create(user_id: params[:player][:user_id], first_name: params[:player][:first_name], last_name: params[:player][:last_name], position: params[:player][:position], favorite_team: params[:player][:favorite_team], extra_equipment: params[:player][:extra_equipment], bio: params[:player][:bio])
        redirect_to players_path
    end
```

player new:

```
<h1>Add a new Player</h1>

<%= form_for @players do |f| %>

<p>First Name   <%= f.text_field :first_name %></p>

<p>Last name    <%= f.text_field :last_name %></p>

<p>Position <%= f.text_field :position %></p>

<p>Favorite Team(optional)  <%= f.text_field :favorite_team %></p>

<p>Extra Equipment  <%= f.text_field :extra_equipment %></p>

<p>Bio  <%= f.text_field :bio %></p>

<%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>

<%= submit_tag "Add"%>

<% end %>
```

Player Model

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :pickup, through: :player_pickup
end
```

Comment: show the `new` action in your controller

Comment: Please add the `Player` model.

Comment: Usually you get a rollback when model validations fail and  I see no validations on Player model. `Player.create!(....)`, what does it say?

Answer (score 1):

For crud (Create, Update, Retrieve & Destroy) use @player, not @players. 
Also, call your params from a private method instead calling it directly, this is a DRY concept in rails.

So it would be somehow like this (example):

```
def new
 @player = Player.new
end

def create
 @player = Player.new(player_params)
 if @player.save 
  // Do something
 else
  // Do something
 end
end

private

def player_params
 params.require(:player).permit(:param_1, :param_2 .... etc)
end
```

**Then** in your view use `form_for @player`

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing a value into the hidden field. You should be doing something like

`<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>`

If the user_id is always the current_user - you don't need a field, you can just assign it in the controller.

```
 def create
  @players = Player.create(first_name: params[:player][:first_name], last_name: params[:player][:last_name], position: params[:player][:position], favorite_team: params[:player][:favorite_team], extra_equipment: params[:player][:extra_equipment], bio: params[:player][:bio])
  @players.user_id = current_user.id
  @players.save
    redirect_to players_path
end
```

Or - if you want to keep the same formatting

```
def create
   @players = Player.create(user_id: current_user.id, first_name: params[:player][:first_name], last_name: params[:player][:last_name], position: params[:player][:position], favorite_team: params[:player][:favorite_team], extra_equipment: params[:player][:extra_equipment], bio: params[:player][:bio])
    redirect_to players_path
end
```